# Get Field in Immediate Child Objects Only Using json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a Json that looks like this which I have parsed using json4s parseJson method:

```
       { 
        "id":123, 
        "item1":[
          {
           "id":"234", 
           "item2":[
             {
              "id":"456"
             }
            ]
           }
          ]
        }
```

I want to get only the id of item1, but not item2. How do I do that using json4s?

If I use json \ "id" I'll get item2's id as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could `jackson's` `\` operator as follow:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

var json = parse("""{"id":123,"item1":[{"id":"234","item2":[{"id":"456"}]}]}""").asInstanceOf[JObject]

json \\ "item1" \\ "id"
//Result: JObject(List((id,JString(234)), (id,JString(456))))

json \ "item1" \ "id"
//Result: JArray(List(JString(234)))
```

Comment: Problem with that approach is that the name of nested object can be anything, not just item1.